# On a property similar to sequentially compact

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space. If $A$ is a subspace of $X$ and every sequence $\{x_n \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ in $A$ has a subsequence $\{x_{n_{k}} \}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ that converges to a point $p$ in $X$ (**$p$ is not necessarily in $A$**), can we prove that $\overline{A}$ has the same property? i.e., Every sequence $\{x_n \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\overline{A}$ has a subsequence $\{x_{n_{k}} \}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ that converges to a point $p$ in $X$.

My thought: if the result does not hold, then we can find a sequence $\{x_n \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\overline{A}\setminus A$ and $\{x_n \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ does not have convergent subsequence in $X$. But can we find a contradiction using this sequence?

Anyway, the construction is as follows:
Suppose the result does not hold. Then $\exists \{x_n \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subset \overline {A} $ s.t. its any subsequence $\{x_{n_{k}} \}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converge. We claim that there are infinite number of $m\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $x_m \in \overline{A}\setminus A$. For otherwise there are only finite number of $m\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $x_m \in \overline{A}\setminus A$. Then we just throw away these $x_m$ from $\{x_n\}$, and the rest subsequence $\{x'_n \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is in $A$, hence it has a convergent subsequence by the property of $A$, contradiction. We thus find a sequence $\{x_m \}_{m\in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\overline{A}\setminus A$ and $\{x_m \}_{m\in \mathbb{N}}$ does not have convergent subsequence in $X$.

Comment: Your argument looks good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see how to proceed with your idea. But here's mine.

Consider a sequence $(x_n)\subseteq \overline{A}$. By the sequential description of $\overline{A}$ we know that for any $m$ there is a sequence $(y_{m,n})\subseteq A$ convergent to $x_m$.

Next consider the sequence $(z_m)$ constructed as follows: $z_m=y_{m,N}$ where $N$ is such that $d(y_{m,N},x_m)<\frac{1}{m}$. Such $N$ exists since $y_{m,n}\to x_m$.

Now since $z_m$ is fully contained in $A$ then $z_m$ has a convergent subsequence, say $z_{m_k}$ converges to $z'$. We will show that $x_{m_k}$ converges to $z'$ as well.

Indeed, this follows from the triangle inequality

$$d(x_{m_k},z')\leq d(x_{m_k},z_{m_k})+d(z_{m_k},z')$$

and the observation that $d(x_{m_k},z_{m_k})$ converges to $0$ because of how $z_m$ was constructed, while $d(z_{m_k},z')$ converges to $0$ because $z_{m_k}$ converges to $z'$ by definition.

Note that in the case of metric spaces such $A$ is called *relatively compact*.